# Amazon SES vs Newsletter services for sending daily automatic e-mails (such as MailChimp)

Tags: email, mailchimp, amazon-ses

The system I'm currently developing dispatching a 'daily report' for all users and for my normal e-mail backend, I use Amazon SES to dispatch such emails.

The question is, which is a better practice, to send such e-mails (which are not really newsletters but status updates) via Amazon SES or should I migrate to a service provider such as MailChimp or Campaign Monitor.

Ps: Right now, I send e-mails asynchronous, using [django-mailer](https://github.com/jtauber/django-mailer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already have everything set up to use Amazon SES, stick with it. It's really an excellent choice for transactional emails. Mailchimp is really more suited for newsletters, and if a mailchimp user wants to send transactional emails, he is referred to a mailchimp sister service called [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/).

The only advantage to migrating an existing system from Amazon SES to Mandrill that comes to my mind is that in Mandrill you can set the "from" email to whatever you want. Often this is usefull for "send to a friend" features. In Amazon SES you currently can't do that.